# Lawvere metrics on the poset of subgroups of Z?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

**Background**: Recall that a *[Lawvere metric](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#LawvereMetricSpace)* structure on a set $X$ consists of a function $d\colon X\times X\to[0,\infty]$ satisfying two properties:

- $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in X$,
- $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)$ for all $x,y,z\in X$.

A *metric* in the usual sense is a Lawvere metric with two extra properties, *separation* and *symmetry*: $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$, for all $x,y\in X$.

**Question**: Consider the set $S:= \{G\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\}$ of all subgroups of the group of integers.

Does there exist a Lawvere metric $d\colon S\times S\to[0,\infty]$ with the properties that:

1. whenever $G\subseteq G'$ is a subgroup, one has $d(G,G')=0$, and
2. there exists some $G,G'$ such that $0<d(G,G')<\infty$?

If so, have any been well-studied or considered interesting or useful in the history of mathematics?

(Note that there is clearly no ordinary metric on $S$ because $0=d(s,0)+d(0,s')\geq d(s,s')$ for all $s,s'\in S$.)

Comment: It would be nice if you recall the definition of a Lawvere metric.

Comment: $d(n\mathbf{Z},m\mathbf{Z})=\log(m/\gcd(n,m))$ for $n,m>0$, $d(\{0\},m\mathbf{Z})=0$, $d(n\mathbf{Z},\{0\})=\infty$ for $n>0$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ be a set and $P(X)$ its powerset. A map $\mu : P(X) \to [0, \infty)$ is *additive* if $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu(A \cup B) + \mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$. Given such an additive map, define a Lawvere metric $d : P(X) \times P(X) \to [0, \infty)$ by
$$
d_\mu(A, B) = \mu (A \setminus B).
$$
We clearly have $d_\mu(A,A) = 0$. For the triangle inequality $d_\mu(A,C) \leq d_\mu(A,B) + d_\mu(B,C)$ just observe that $A \setminus C \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus C)$ (unless I am not able to draw Venn diagrams anymore).
Also notice that $A \subseteq B$ implies $d_\mu(A,B) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

Now to get your desired Lawvere metric on subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$, just take any additive map on $P(\mathbb{Z})$, for instance
$$\mu(A) = \sum_{k \in A} 2^{-|k|}.$$
The map $\mu$ is bounded, so we always have $\mu(A) < \infty$.

For subgroups $G, G' \leq \mathbb{Z}$ the desired properties hold because the metric is bounded and
$$G \subseteq G' \iff d_\mu(G, G') = 0.$$

Comment: Your Venn diagram is fine, provided the law of the excluded middle holds (more precisely: provided $B$ is complemented).

Comment: Excluded middle is like candy to me.